# Label for Second Activity will not change

Tags: android, android-activity

I created a second activity and named it Second Activity when I created it yet when I go look at the Graphical Layout, it still has the name of the project rather then the name I gave it. I go to the AndriodManifest and see the below is in there:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.myTestApp.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
  </activity>
```

And then I look at the string.xml and make sure the string was created and it was.

```
 <string name="title_activity_second">Second Activty</string>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you set the TextView's text value of the layout of Second Activity as the string `title_activity_second`?

Comment: It's not a TextView.  It's the label of the activity; the title in the black rectangle at the top.

Comment: Did you try programmatically using `setTitle("Second Activity");` in your second activity? Is it working if you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that on Graphical Layout, the activity (actually, all layouts) always shows the application title (`android:label` inside `<application>` tag). However, if you run the app, it will be displayed properly both on emulator and real device.

I don't know if it's really a bug or status by-design by Google because I couldn't find anything reported related to this.

Comment: I had not launched the SecondActivity yet.  I just thought I was doing something wrong.